# Unable to rollback my transaction changes

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, rollback

I have one small question I am trying to run my procedure in  anonymous block in a loop in that procedure some jobs are running .once that procedure executed again my job is running in same block .

I want to rollback my all the procedure changes when job in main transaction failed. Is this possible. Can we rollback job changes?

For example:

```
declare
begin
  begin
    For I in 1..3
    loop
      Savepoint ABC;
      Proc1();//calling a procedure which inside calling another job
    end loop;
  end;

  Sys.Dbms_Job ();//run a job then

  if above sys job = 'Faliled' // want to rollback my all procedure changes
    rollback to ABC;
  end if;

end;
```

Comment: Why is your savepoint inside the loop? It should be either before or after it.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if `sys.dbms_job()` did a `commit` at some point

Comment: @boneist I tried savepoint before loop but nothing happened.seems when sys job executed previous changes automatically autocommited. M i ryt?

Comment: @SAMSAM tbh, this doesn't sound like the right approach. If you could edit your question to include more details, such as what your proc1 and jobs are doing, why you want to rollback the job, etc. Chances are that you're overthinking your transactions. Perhaps what you want is a commit before the dbms_job step, and a rollback in whatever the job is doing? It's hard to say without knowing more about what you're trying to do.